# No makefile created for opencv_contrib

Tags: c++, makefile, opencv3.1, opencv-contrib

I'm trying to add the opencv_contrib package to my OpenCV 3.1 build. I am currently using the library in Microsoft Visual Studio 15. I have installed Cmake and GNU Make, cloned the opencv_contrib repo, and followed the instructions on https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib for building the package. The instructions are:

```
C:\Opencv310\build>cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=C:\opencv_contrib\modules C:\Opencv310/sources
C:\Opencv310\build>make -j5
```

The first line runs fine and finishes with the couts:

```
--Configuring done
--Generating done
--Build files have been written to: C:Opencv310\build
```

When I run the final line i get the error:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

Has anyone of you guys ever encountered this error before while adding opencv_contrib? Do you see any errors in what I have done? Any help would be appreciated!

The full output from the first call is:

```
C:\Opencv310\build>cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=C:\opencv_contrib\modules C:\Opencv310\sources
-- found IPP (ICV version): 9.0.1 [9.0.1]
-- at: C:/Opencv310/sources/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_win
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)
-- To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass          -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.12", but     required is at least "3.4" (found C:/Python27/python.exe)
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.12", but     required is at least "3.2" (found C:/Python27/python.exe)
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY     JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH)
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS     MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH     MATLAB_BIN)
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- Caffe:   NO
-- Protobuf:   NO
-- Glog:   NO
-- Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not     found: Eigen Glog/Gflags
-- Could NOT find Protobuf (missing:  Protobuf_LIBRARIES Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Build libprotobuf from sources:
--     libprotobuf not found into system
--     The protocol buffer compiler not found
-- Tesseract:   NO
-- Check contents of vgg_generated_48.i ...
-- Check contents of vgg_generated_64.i ...
-- Check contents of vgg_generated_80.i ...
-- Check contents of vgg_generated_120.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_bgm.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_bgm_bi.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_bgm_hd.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_binboost_064.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_binboost_128.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_binboost_256.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_lbgm.i ...
--
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.1.0     =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
--
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Windows 10.0.14393 AMD64
--     CMake:                       3.7.0-rc2
--     CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015
--     CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files     (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
--     MSVC:                        1900
--
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual     Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.24210.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D     _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS     /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast  /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4589 /MP4  /MD    /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG  /Zi
--     C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D     _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS     /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast  /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4589 /MP4      /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
--     C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
--     C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast    /MP4  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG  /Zi
--     C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D   _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS  /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast    /MP4  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
--     Linker flags (Release):      /machine:X86  /INCREMENTAL:NO  /debug
--     Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:X86  /debug /INCREMENTAL
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32 vfw32
--     3rdparty dependencies:       zlib libjpeg libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf libprotobuf
--
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml photo reg surface_matching video dnn fuzzy imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect plot superres ts xobjdetect xphoto bgsegm bioinspired dpm face features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib datasets rgbd stereo structured_light tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow stitching
--     Disabled:                    world contrib_world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python2 python3 viz cvv hdf matlab sfm
--
--   Windows RT support:            NO
--
--   GUI:
--     QT:                          NO
--     Win32 UI:                    YES
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
--
--   Media I/O:
--     ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
--     PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.19)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
--
--   Video I/O:
--     Video for Windows:           YES
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
--       codec:                     YES (ver 56.41.100)
--       format:                    YES (ver 56.36.101)
--       util:                      YES (ver 54.27.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
--       resample:                  NO
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     DirectShow:                  YES
--     Media Foundation:            NO
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Intel PerC:                  NO
--
--   Parallel framework:            Concurrency
--
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
--          at:                     C:/Opencv310/sources/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_win
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--     Use custom HAL:              NO
--
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                C:/Opencv310/sources/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
--
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 C:/Python27/python.exe (ver 2.7.12)
--
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 NO
--
--   Python (for build):            C:/Python27/python.exe
--
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
--
--   Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled
--
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     NO
--     PlantUML:                    NO
--
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              NO
--
--   Install path:                  C:/Opencv310/build/install
--
--   cvconfig.h is in:              C:/Opencv310/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Opencv310/build
```

Comment: what bit version are you trying to compile? Is it 64-bit or 32-bit?

Answer (score 0):

> --     CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015

You've generated a Visual Studio 2015 solution. Run `cmake` with `-G "NMake Makefiles"` or `"MinGW Makefiles"` if you don't want to use VS.